# Vuex strict mode throws exception while updating nested array

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex

I have a page where user can edit multiple segments. Every segment has a name and an array of filters that he can added/removed.

```
{
  segments: [
    {
      name: 'Mac',
      filters: [
        {
          field: 'os',
          value: 'mac'
        },
        {
          field: 'browser',
          value: 'chrome'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**Index.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="segments">
    <segment
      v-for="segment in segments"
      :id="segment.id"
      :name="segment.name"
      :filters="segment.filters">
    </segment>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Segment from './Segment'
export default {
  vuex: {
    getters: {
      segments
    }
  },
  components: {
    Segment
  }
}
</script>
```

**Segment.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="segment">
    <input type="text" class="name" v-model="name" />
    <filters :filters="segment.filters"></filters>
    <button @click="saveSegment()">Save</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Filters from './Filters'
export default {
  props: ['id', 'name', 'filters'],
  vuex: {
    methods: {
      updateSegment({dispatch}, id, segments) {
        dispatch(SEGMENT_UPDATE, id, segment)
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    save () {
      this.updateSegment(this.id, {
        name: this.name,
        filters: this.filters
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Filters.vue**

```
<template>
  <ul class="filters">
    <li v-for="filter in filter">
      {{ filter.name }} <button @click="remove($index)">Remove</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['filters'],
  methods: {
    remove (index) {
      this.filters.splice(index, 1)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Every time I remove a filter, I get `Do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation handlers.` error. And I know why, because no matter how many times I pass filters array through components properties, they still remain reactive and their change in Filters component propagates down to the vuex store that throws an error.

Same will be with segments names in inputs. But there is an example how to handle forms in docs.

But how can I make filters work? Make separate stores for filters? But it will be a mess because there will be multiple segments with their own filters on the page... I'm stuck :(

Comment: I think you're supposed to send an event to cue the removal.

Answer (score 0):

As well as I understood from the conversation in the vuex repo itself, the only way and the best decision is to deep clone the `filters` array and then just use it as a local variable.

It has to be done because arrays in JS always passed by reference and deep clone unbinds my `filters` array from the one in the vuex store.

This can be achieved by `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())`, `_.cloneDeep()` or any other similarmethod.